# pass HttpClient to constructor via useFactory

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have updated my app to angular 5, before I had angular 2 and my common mock looked like that

```
export class CommonMocks{
    static HttpMocks(): any[] {
     return{
      provide: myAppHttpHandler,
            useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => {
              return new myAppHttpHandler(http)
            }
           }
      }
  }
}
```

after the upgrade I changed myAppHttpHandler class to this:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
export class myAppHttpHandler{
 constructor(http:HttpClient){} //was Http from @angular/http
}
```

and now I get an error when I try to run tests:

**zone.js?fad3:169 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for useFactory: (?).**

Can anyone explain what should I do with minimum changes?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `deps`?

Comment: no what should I write in deps?

Comment: `deps: [HttpClient]`

Comment: Working :) Thank you !!!!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear